# java from a program that runs 1000 times in a row to muli threading

Tags: java, multithreading

i am still new to java in run this code arround 1000 time in a row now so its probably mutch more efficent to run it multithread but i have no idea what the best idea is to give the score back to the main thread

```
    private int StartGameRandom(EntityManager managerOrg, UserInput input)
{
    EntityManager manager = managerOrg.cloneState(managerOrg);
    int playerId = 0;
    int score = 0;

    //get the player id from the player that has to play
    ArrayList<Entity> tempState = manager.getAllWithComponents(PhaseComponent.class);
    if (tempState.isEmpty())
        System.err.println("ScoreSystem.addScorePlayer noPlayerComponent found");
    Entity state = tempState.get(0);
    PhaseComponent sComponent = (PhaseComponent) state.getComponent(PhaseComponent.class);
    playerId = sComponent.getPlayerId();

    SetPlayersToRandom(manager);
    new PhaseSystem(manager, input);

    ArrayList<Entity> tempPlayer = manager.getAllWithComponents(PlayerComponent.class);
    if (tempPlayer.isEmpty())
        System.err.println("montecarlo.startgamerandom noPlayerComponent found");
    Entity[] players = new Entity[tempPlayer.size()];
    tempPlayer.toArray(players);

    //set all the players to random ai
    for (Entity entity : players) {
        PlayerComponent component = (PlayerComponent) entity.getComponent(PlayerComponent.class);
        if (component.getPlayerID() == (byte)playerId)
        {
            score = component.getTotalScore();
            break;
        }
    }

    return score;
}
```

this is what i do with the scores

```
                    for (int j = 0; j < RUNS; j++ )
                {
                    int score = StartGameRandom(manager,input);
                    maxScore = Math.max(score, maxScore);
                    if (j == 0)
                    {
                        minScore = score;
                        averageScore  = score;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        minScore = Math.min(score, minScore);

                        averageScore  = ((averageScore*j)+score)/(j+1);
                    }
                }
```

so what is the best way to do this in java

Comment: what do you mean by run 1000 times in a row? Could explain a little better what is your objective?

Comment: The first question should be to ask if you have profiled your code and are certain that this is actually a bottleneck.  Computers are incredibly fast and the overhead from using threads can easily outweigh any benefits.

Comment: if you look to the 2cond code part you see the line 
for (int j = 0; j < RUNS; j++ ) the runs will be > 1000.
The runtime for this is now arround 10 mintus.
So i was tinking to split it up in threads that run for example 100 runs but i dont know what the best way to do this is

Comment: Have the threads call into a synchronized method outside of themselves (maybe in your main thread) to update the min and average scores.

Answer (score 2):

Making stuff multithreaded doesn't automatically make things faster. Indeed, multithreading shouldn't be your first option for optimization.

I'm not entirely sure what your code does, but from the fact that it's taking 10 minutes and an `EntityManager` is involved, I'm guessing that the DB calls are the culprit.

You should investigate how much time you are spending on each part and see if your DB queries are inefficient, or if you are making lots of separate calls (that you could merge into fewer calls).

Comment: its a board game that i made to learn more about ai the ones that i am currently implementing in it are mcts min/max monte carlo method 1 of the reasons it takes that long i run on evry move that i have to make in 1 of my ai the game arround 1000 times and the game has a lot of moves if i set 2 random ai on its a matter of seconds to run the game